# Exiting a For Loop & Enumeration (Python)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, exit, enumerate

I'm new to Python and working on a bootcamp project... and I'm absolutely making it harder than it needs to be...

What I'm looking to ultimately do, is create the following:

1. Name: Titanic \n
   Director: Spielberg \n
   Year: 1997 \n\n
2. Name: The Matrix \n
   Director: Waskowskis \n
   Year: 1996 \n\n

*AFTER* I've added them with the "(A)dd Movie function... So, firstly, I can't seem to 'exit' the For Loop... once I run it, it just repeats indefinitely... and beyond that, I'm not able to get the formatting correct if I try to use "enumerate".

Here's my code: (the portion I'm talking about is under the "def show_movies" function:

```
import sys
import random
import os
movies = []


def menu():
    global user_input
    print("Welcome to 'The Movie Program!!'")
    print("(A)dd movie to your list")
    print("(L)ist movies you've added")
    print("(S)earch for movies in your list")
    user_input = str(input("Which function would you like to do?:\n\n""Selection: ").capitalize())
    while user_input != 'Q':
        if user_input == 'A':
            add_movies()
        elif user_input == 'L':
            show_movies()
        elif user_input == 'A':
            search_movies()
        else:
            print("\n\n--Unknown command--Please try again.\n")
            print("Welcome to 'The Movie Program!!'")
            print("(A)dd movie to your list")
            print("(L)ist movies you've added")
            print("(S)earch for movies in your list")
            user_input = str(input("Which FUNCTION would you like to do?:\n\n""Selection: ").capitalize())


def add_movies():
    #name = (input('What is the title of the movie?: ').title())
    #director = str(input("Who was the director of this movie?: ").title())
    year = None
    while True:
        try:
            name = (input('What is the title of the movie?: ').title())
            director = str(input("Who was the director of this movie?: ").title())
            year = int(input("What was the release year?: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Only numbers, please.")
            continue
        movies.append({
            "name": name,
            "director": director,
            "year": year
        })
        break
    menu()


    add_movies()


def show_movies():
        for movie in movies:
            print(f"Name: {movie['name']}")
            print(f"Director: {movie['director']}")
            print(f"Release Year: {movie['year']}\n")
            #continue
            #break


def search_movies():
    movies
    print("This is where you'd see a list of movies in your database")


menu()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `while user_input != 'Q':` loop.

If `user_input` is equal to `L`, then it calls `show_movies()`, but doesn't ask for more input. It just goes round and round the `while` loop calling `show_movies()` each time.

You should input `user_input` again each time through the loop, not only in your `else` clause.

```
while user_input != 'Q':
    if user_input == 'A':
        add_movies()
    elif user_input == 'L':
        show_movies()
    elif user_input == 'A':
        search_movies()
    else:
        print("\n\n--Unknown command--Please try again.\n")
        print("Welcome to 'The Movie Program!!'")
        print("(A)dd movie to your list")
        print("(L)ist movies you've added")
        print("(S)earch for movies in your list")
    # the next line is now outside your `else` clause
    user_input = str(input("Which FUNCTION would you like to do?:\n\nSelection: ").capitalize())
```

Comment: I would recommend to move the whole menu out of the `else` together with the `user_input` assignment to the top of the loop and not having almost the same code twice in that program. And then using an ”endless” loop (`while True:`) and leave that with `break` when the user has entered `Q`.